# Auto-scale an image in GridView

Tags: android, android-imageview, grid-layout, android-gridlayout

I have a simple grid view with an image on the left and two lines of text right beside the image. The "rowspan" of the image is 2 in order to use the full height of the two lines of text:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:rowCount="2"
    android:columnCount="2">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_column="0"
    android:layout_row="0"
    android:layout_rowSpan="2"
    android:src="@drawable/disconnected" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/connectionText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:layout_column="1"
    android:layout_row="0"
    android:layout_rowSpan="1"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:text="Name" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/stateText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:layout_column="1"
    android:layout_row="1"
    android:layout_rowSpan="1"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:text="disconnected" />
</GridLayout>
```

My problem: I would like to auto-scale the image to a size which fits to the height of the two lines of text instead of appearing with it's native height. Is there a way to let the Layout do that automatically?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:rowCount="2"
        android:columnCount="2">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:layout_rowSpan="2"
        android:src="@drawable/disconnected" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/connectionText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_rowSpan="1"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="Name" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/stateText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_rowSpan="1"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="disconnected" />
</GridLayout>
```

I have modified your xml, it may help.
I have given specific width and height value and set the scale type to fit center.

you can set dynamic height by programming, this code will help you

```
        int first_view_hight = firstView.getLineHeight(); 


        int second_view_height = secondView.getLineHeight();


        int totalHeight = first_view_hight + second_view_height;


        GridLayout.LayoutParams lp = (GridLayout.LayoutParams) setHeightImage.getLayoutParams();
        lp.height = totalHeight;
        lp.width = totalHeight;
        imageView.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

Comment: Hm, but this scales to a fixed size of 40x40 dp and not dynamically to the real size of the two lines of text right beside it!?